# Conditional if/then for gt: in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, conditional-statements

How do you say :

```
if there are more than 2 .quick_fact then
```

My attempt:

```
if $(".quick_fact:gt(2)") { }
```

Which evidently is always true.

Comment: Yours fails because no matter what `selector` is in `$(selector)`, it will always return a jquery object, which isn't going to be false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A jQuery object has a `length` property representing the number of matched elements. So simply do a typical "greater than" comparison.

```
if( $('.quick_fact').length > 2 ) {
    // There were more than two
}
```

Comment: Answer avalanche... you got me.

Comment: You guys just rocked my jQuorld.

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($(".quick_fact").size() > 2 ) { }
```

Or:

```
if ($(".quick_fact").length > 2 ) { }
```